# how to mark a city in google map

Tags: php, google-maps, maps

I am making a project n which we are giving services area wise by our local stores. like 100 stores in gurgaon, 110 stores in delhi etc

Now I want to show these area in google map like 
[image]

if user searches stores in gurgaon then mark place like above.

So please tell if marking like this is possible by freely provided api from google.
or I have to write some code for it....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mark the stores location you should use [Complex Icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex?hl=es), and if you want also to open a panel showing for example the store address, then you can use [Info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=es).

If you want to generate those maps with Complex Icons and Info windows using only PHP and you are using a PHP framework like Kohana, you can achieve that using the [Google Maps Module](https://github.com/juanparati/kohana-gmaps3) that I developed some years ago. The module is able to generate the Javascript code required for generate complex google maps with icons, complex icons, polylines, infopanels, etc.

An example:

```
$map = Gmaps3::instance();

/* Generate a simple mark */
// We can use chainable methods
$map->add_mark(56.177668, 10.103302)// Coordinates  
    ->set('view_shadow', TRUE)      // View icons shadows
    ->center(FALSE);                // Center map relative to this mark but without autofit zoom



/* Generate a draggable yellow mark */
$map->add_mark(56.005628, 10.02305, 'My draggable mark', TRUE, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png');

$template = View::factory('gmaps')
            ->set('external_scripts', $map->get_apilink())
            ->set('internal_scripts', $map->get_map('map_container'))
            ->render(); 

$this->response->body($template);
```

In order to display the number inside the mark, you have to generate  the numbered icons or use a [pre-generated icons](http://sparce.cs.pdx.edu/mash-o-matic/tools.html).

Comment: hi juan lago thanks for your answer, downloaded files from git hub now checking if it works or not